# POM file after adding the new repository

Tags: maven, benerator

POM file after adding the new repository..

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>3.3.9</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>myproject data generation project</name>
<description>Start populating the database by typing 'mvn benerator:generate' on the command line.</description>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.databene</groupId>
<artifactId>databene-benerator</artifactId>
<version>0.9.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.databene</groupId>
<artifactId>dbsanity</artifactId>
<version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.databene</groupId>
<artifactId>jdbacl</artifactId>
<version>0.8.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.databene</groupId>
<artifactId>benerator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>0.9.8</version>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
<groupId>org.databene</groupId>
<artifactId>databene-webdecs-0.8.4</artifactId>
<version>0.8.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.databene</groupId>
<artifactId>databene-commons</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.databene</groupId>
<artifactId>contiperf</artifactId>
<version>1.07</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
 <repository>
 <id>org.databene</id>
  <url>http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.databene/databene-benerator</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.1</version>
<configuration>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<source>1.5</source>
<target>1.5</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.databene</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-benerator-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.9.8</version>
<configuration>
               <descriptor>C:\Users\sudarsan\Desktop\myproject\benerator.xml</descriptor>
<encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
 <validate>true</validate>
  <dbUrl>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datagenerator</dbUrl>
  <dbDriver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</dbDriver>
   <dbSchema>root</dbSchema>
   <dbUser>root</dbUser>
   <dbPassword>generator</dbPassword>
  </configuration>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId> <!-- MS SQL server and Sybase -->
 <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
<version>1.2.2</version>
 <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>mysql</groupId>
 <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
 <version>5.1.6</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
  <dependency>
 <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
<artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
 <version>1.8.0.7</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
<artifactId>h2</artifactId>
<version>1.2.132</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
 <version>3.8</version>
 <scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
<!-- logging -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
 <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<version>1.6.4</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

As u mentioned, i found the new repository at mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.databene/benerator-maven-plugin/… tried to edit the POM but getting the error as

[WARNING] The POM for org.databene:benerator-maven-plugin:jar:jar is missing, no dependency information available. [ERROR] Plugin org.databene:benerator-maven-plugin:jar or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.databene:benerator-maven-plugin:jar:jar in central (repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you follow the steps from the [official start guide](http://databene.org/maven-benerator-plugin)? did you add to your pom the minimal plugin definition?

Comment: By the way, you should keep build-related files somewhere under the project folder and reference them via a relative path, instead of absolute like you do here: `<descriptor>C:\Users\sudarsan\Desktop\myproject\benerator.xml</descriptor>`

Answer (score 0):

Official Maven repository (which you are probably using as it's default) doesn't contain version 0.9.8 of this plugin: 
http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.databene%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-benerator-plugin%22

The Databene repo contains a few more versions, so you can customize maven to use this repo, but it still doesn't have version 0.9.8:
http://databene.org/m2/org/databene/maven-benerator-plugin/

To use Databene repo add this to your pom.xml (applies to project) or ~/.m2/settings.xml (applies to user):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>databene</id>
        <url>http://databene.org/m2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

This will allow you to use version 0.9.0. If you know some other Maven repository that contains 0.9.8, simply add that repository instead and use 0.9.8.

**UPDATE:**

Looks like the plugin got renamed to [`benerator-maven-plugin`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.databene|benerator-maven-plugin|0.9.8|maven-plugin) to adhere to Maven plugin naming guidelines. So it should be enough to just use version 0.9.8 with the new name.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply,

Comment: I have tried to add the above to repo,its not working , i tried the mvn help:effective-pom command to generate effective POM.xml and tried to generate the command, Now also it is not working

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Maven should report what it tried to download and what failed, so you should be able to verify it's using correct path to download this plugin.

Comment: No plugin found for prefix 'benerator' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\sudarsan\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

Comment: There should be additional information in the log about how Maven attempts to find the plugin. It's rather hard to guess what's wrong without that. Can you also try running the plugin explicitly and check for logs related to which repositories Maven is checking and what is the result? To run explicitly: `mvn org.databene:maven-benerator-plugin:jar:0.9.0:generate`

Comment: plz find the details : [WARNING] The POM for org.databene:benerator-maven-plugin:jar:jar is missing, no dependency information available.  [ERROR] Plugin org.databene:benerator-maven-plugin:jar or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.databene:benerator-maven-plugin:jar:jar in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]   As u mentioned, i found the new repository at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.databene/benerator-maven-plugin/0.9.8,i tried to edit the POM but getting the error as above.. Plz find the POM file

Comment: Plz find the POM file in the above section

Comment: Ah, basically the plugin got renamed. It's now called `benerator-maven-plugin` to adhere to Maven guidelines, instead of previous `maven-benerator-plugin`. So you can fix everything easily by just using the new plugin name. Specifying a repository should not be necessary, because it's simply under the new name in the default repository.